# PHP and MySQL checkbox inserting as 3 for bit column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a checkbox like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="local" />
```

and in PHP I am converting it to:

```
$local = isset($_POST['local']) ? 1 : 0;
```

and Inserting into a database table like so:

```
"INSERT INTO table (local) VALUES ('" . $local . "');"
```

It does save the database but the value is 3 for some reason.

The column local is defined as:

```
`local` bit(2) NOT NULL,
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: You should parameterize query but that likely isn't the issue. `var_dump($local)` gives what?

Comment: There must be something else changing `$local`, because this shouldn't do that.

Comment: remove the quotes around $local

Answer (score 0):

> The BIT data type is used to store bit values. A type of BIT(M) enables storage of M-bit values. M can range from 1 to 64.

As you need to store only `0` or `1` try to define your `local` column as: `local BIT(1) NOT NULL`